# How exactly is user.name and user.email linked to commits? How to get those from commits?

Tags: git

I remember long time ago I read that setting email for git commits gets you spam.

How exactly are user.email and user.name linked to commits? Is it possible to view them by cloning the project, or viewing it?

Is there a way of getting hold of the email in an unauthorized way?

Comment: git config --global user.name "name"  && git config --global user.email "email"  are used for configuring the user-name and email id which git uses.  You can check the same with "git config --list"  command to view them.

Answer (score 4):

This is the structure of a commit, you can see that the name and email are part of the commit data

[image]

---

> Is it possible to view them by cloning the project, or viewing it?

```
git log
```

it will display the commit message with all the other metadata that you see in the green box in the image.

---

> Is there a way of getting hold of the email in an unauthorized way?

No. you can use any email you want by passing `git commit -c user.name "aaa" -c user.email "a@a.net"` the `-c` will overwrite any configuration you may have inside your config file.

Answer (score 2):

Every commit contains the author and committer email addresses of that commit within the commit metadata.  For instance, the latest commit to kernel development git repository on kernel.org:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/

You'll notice an `author` and a `committer` tag containing names and email addresses.

On github, you will see similar information in the `From:` tag when you view a raw patch (add `.patch` to the end of any commit url that you are viewing)  For example:

https://github.com/mkrufky/linux/commit/master.patch

I believe the above answers your question. As mentioned in the comments, you can set this using `git config --global user.name "Your Name" && git config --global user.email "your@email.address"`, or you can modify `~/.gitconfig` directly to include the following:

```
[user]
        name = Your Full Name
        email = your.email@addr.ess
```